# Covid19 B2 visa extension online- response from USCIS

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, covid-19

When should I expect a response from USCIS about visa extension due to Covid19?

Also, does it make sense to pay for biometrics when offices are closed? When I tried to complete the I 539 form, I was asked to pay $455 which includes biometrics. I am not sure if I should.

Answer (score 1):

The [USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/about-us/uscis-response-covid-19) publishes this advice regarding the extension of a US visa:

> Generally, nonimmigrants must depart the United States before their authorized period of admission expires. However, we recognize that nonimmigrants may unexpectedly remain in the United States beyond their authorized period of stay should apply for an extension or change of status in advance. Should this occur, the following options are available to nonimmigrants:
>
> **Apply for an Extension.** Most nonimmigrants can mitigate the immigration consequences of COVID-19 by timely filing an application for extension of stay (EOS) or change in status (COS). U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services continues to accept and process applications and petitions, and many of our forms are available for online filing.

No biometrics need to be paid for since offices are closed.

Comment: The application fee is $355 and biometric is $100 so when I was about to submit the form, I was asked to pay $455, so I am confused as all offices are closed for biometrics

Comment: @KaviKavethanjana are you talking about an application for an extension?

Comment: Do you have a source to support the conclusion that because offices are closed no biometrics fee is required?  I rather suspect that applicants will be expected to provide biometrics once it becomes possible to do so.